# Understanding fields and their correlation to forces

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I seem to be confused between the concept of a "force", and a field.
Now let's assume there is a magnetic field of $1$ $\mathrm{Tesla}$, what does that mean in relation to force?

Finally, if field is $1$ $\mathrm{Tesla}$ does that always mean, the force at that field is always the same? 
Example a magnetic field source (From Solenoid) of $1$ $\mathrm{Tesla}$ can apply a force of $10,000$ $\mathrm{Newtons}$, magnetic field source (Permanent Magnet) generates the same field strength, at the same conditions does it produce the same force?

Comment: From Wikipedia article "Tesla (unit)":  *A particle carrying a charge of 1 coulomb and passing through a magnetic field of 1 tesla at a speed of 1 meter per second perpendicular to said field experiences a force with magnitude 1 newton*.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri this seems extremely familiar to Lorentz force... But that is not the case of a ferromagnet attracted to the field, I assume it parallel to the field.

Comment: @Key: fundamentally, all magnetic forces are due to the Lorentz force on moving charges.  Even ferromagnets have their roots in the spinning of charged electrons.

Answer (score 1):

No, magnetic field does not determined force alone. Force depends on other things. If the force discussed is magnetic force on a moving eletric charge, the force is given by

$$
q \mathbf v\times \mathbf B
$$
in SI units. Here $q$ is electric charge of the particle,  $\mathbf v$ its velocity and $\mathbf B$ is magnetic field.

If the force is magnetic force on a piece of uncharged or static body, then the formula is more complicated and depends on the magnetization, shape and orientation of the body. In the simplest case of a small body in time independent magnetic field, the net magnetic force is given by

$$
\mathbf m \cdot \nabla \mathbf B
$$
were $\mathbf m$ is magnetic moment of the body. In more complicated cases (force of big electromagnet on a car), net EM force on the body may be calculated with help of the Maxwell stress tensor.

Answer (score 0):

A force is experimented by a charge when you put in in presence of a field. The strength of the  force is a function not only of the strength of the field, but also of the strength of the charge. So, in a given electric field, a larger charge will experience a larger force. The classical concept of a field is more useful than that of force in the sense that is more general, because you can calculate the strength of a field regardless of the particles or stuff that is going to experience it. You can compute the field once, and it allows to quickly compute the force experimented by a variety of test particles put on it. I could go much deeper about how historically fields became a fundamental concept in modern physics instead of that of force. But I believe that is beyond your question